# QDoubleSpinBox value() returning incorrect double value

Tags: c++, qt

I'm accessing a value set on a `QDoubleSpinBox` by calling`value()` function.

```
mydoublespinbox->value();
```

**Scenario 1**
Visible value on the control is **899.9823**
value() function returns: **899.982** (last decimal place is missing)

**Scenario 2**
When entered value is **99.9823** `value()` function returns the correct value **99.9823**

What's wrong in the 1st scenario?

Comment: I suppose it is because of the implicit parameters of displaying, std::cout is also doing so: it represent 9.99823e-2, 0.99823, 9.9823, 99.9823, 999.823, 9998.23, 99982.3, 999823 even if there are more decimals, in other words, it is doing an approximation on decimals depending on how representative are they

Comment: Thanks @sop Your comment led me to find the solution to my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to grab the value onto a `QString` variable. Following code segment does the trick

```
QString::number(mydouble_spinbox->value(), 'f', mydouble_spinbox->decimals());
```

[Related Qt Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#number-2)